# phpspreadsheet not working IIS (Windows server 2012 R2) BUT working on local XAMPP Server

Tags: php, iis

I have developed a website using php & mysql where the user have to upload a excel file.
In local server (XAMPP), I have download phpspreadsheet and I am able to upload excel file to mysql database. But when I am working in same thing on IIS (Windows server 2012 r2), excel file not upload to mysql and below basic code not working on IIS (Windows server 2012 r2) and show

> This page isn’t working. 10.10.10.2 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

In IIS windows server 2012 r2, I am using php 7.4.13.Below code working on XAMPP SERVER but not working on IIS (Windows server 2012 R2)

```
<?php

require 'vendor/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'This new hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('ThisMyExcelExample.xlsx');
?>
```

Comment: Error 500 is a general error, you need to check error logs (or display the errors) to see what it actually is failing on.

Comment: how to check error logs? I am using core php .

Comment: Now i am able to insert excel file to mysql(IIS-WIN SERVER 2012).  when $writer->save('ThisMyExcelExample.xlsx') line executed, write permission denied. After provide write permission to authentic users in project folder, $writer->save('ThisMyExcelExample.xlsx') line executed successfully .

Comment: What's the application pool identity you set? It seems that you use IIS to write excel file to SQL. So you need to make sure that IIS has permission to read and write to SQL or folder. Right click the folder and add `IIS APPPOOL\pool name` to security item and give it full control permission.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server, there are more steps involved.
make sure that you made the following steps

- Open the Server Manager application and go through the “Add Roles and
  Features” wizard.
- On the Server Roles page, select “Web Server (IIS)”**, be sure to enable CGI**
- Installing PHP on IIS
- In the Actions pane, you will be able to choose “Add Module Mapping.” Enter the necessary details to tell IIS that *.php files should be run by php-cgi.exe
- Now, select your server in the Connections pane of IIS Manager and choose “Default Document.” In the subsequent Actions pane, click “Add…” and add “index.php.”
- also make sure to configure PHP on IIS

please check the following article [How to Host PHP on windows with IIS](https://stackify.com/how-to-host-php-on-windows-with-iis/)
its helpful & will guide you with attached images of steps

Comment: I would have thought that if they are getting an error 500, they are actually running the script and it's failing.

Comment: Now i am able to insert excel file to mysql(IIS-WIN SERVER 2012). when $writer->save('ThisMyExcelExample.xlsx') line executed, write permission denied. After provide write permission to authentic users in project folder, $writer->save('ThisMyExcelExample.xlsx') line executed successfully .